# Click Bottom counter in website : I want a way to make the counter complete (continue) from where it arrived after reloading a page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a counter bottom on my site. To do so, I did that and the code is at the bottom, but the problem is that the counter returns to zero when reloading the webpage. What is the solution?

I want a way to make the counter complete (continue) from where it arrived after reloading a page.

Here is my click Bottom code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function hello() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="hello()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: Why python tag?

Comment: search for localStorage!

Comment: If you want that counter number to be unique and incremental across the user, the browser then that number must be stored at the database and also fetch it from the database, with local storage or other option will not work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to storage the counter.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!localStorage.getItem("counter"))
    localStorage.setItem("counter", 0);
    function hello() {
        localStorage.counter += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = localStorage.counter;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Note that I want to upload the site on the Internet , and I want the number to be on the same counter for everyone and when some one click the button the number is increase on the counter for everyone

Comment: @العلمحياةScienceLife Then that counter must be stored to the database and share across the user, browser and fetch it when user logged in

Comment: How can I have database ? , and if I have it , is the number in counter will change to everyone when someone click button's counter

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello() {
        let clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
        if(localStorage.getItem('clicks') && clicks)
        {
          clicks += 1; 
          localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
        }
        else
        {
          clicks = 0;
          clicks += 1;
          localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
        }
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="hello()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks"></a></p>
```

**Note::**

If you want that counter number to be unique and incremental across the user, the browser then that number must be stored at the database and also fetch it from the database, with any browser storage will not help you in any case!

Comment: How can I have database ? , and if I have it , is the number in counter will change to everyone when someone click button's counter

Comment: What front end you are using?